# Unclear execution of small program with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I created a test program uses threads:

```
class First implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("One ");
    }
}

class Second implements Runnable {
    Thread other;
    Second(Thread t) {other = t;}
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Two");
    }
}

public class ThreadTest {
    void go() {
        First first = new First();
        Thread t = new Thread(first);
        Second second = new Second(t);
        Thread u = new Thread(second);
        t.start();
        u.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().go();
    }
}
```

I expected that it will print:

> One
>   One

But it suddenly for me had printed:

> One
>   Two

I don't understand why this is happening. I thought that in both threads, the method `run()` from First class must be called. Because I passed First instance into Thread constructor and then pass this created thread into Second constructor. So method `run()` from First class has priority over `run()` method from Second class. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why the second thread should print `"One"`.  It may have a reference to the first `Thread`, but it does nothing with it.  Nothing overrides `Second`'s `run` method, so it just prints `Two`.

To make the second `Thread` print `One`, have `run` call the other `Thread`'s `run` method.

```
class Second implements Runnable {
    Thread other;
    Second(Thread t) {other = t;}
    public void run() {
        other.run();
    }
}
```

But it's unusual to call one `Thread`'s `run` method from the `run` method of another `Thread`.  In fact, it's unusual to call `run` directly at all.

Comment: Thank you! I was very inattentive

Answer (score 1):

> I expected that it will print:  One One  But it suddenly for me had printed: One Two

You are starting 2 threads.  The `First.run()` method prints out "One".  The `Second.run()` method prints out "Two".  Just because you assign `other = t;` in the `Second` constructor does not change it's `run()` method.

> Because I passed First instance into Thread constructor and then pass this created thread into Second constructor. So method run() from First class has priority over run() method from Second class. Where am I wrong

Maybe in the `Second.run()` method you meant to call `other.run()` or something?  That would be a strange pattern however that is not recommended.  You should not link `Thread` classes like that.  You should probably pass in the `First` method and then do:

```
class Second implements Runnable {
    First first;
    Second(First first) { this.first = first; }
    public void run() {
        first.run();
    }
}
```

But even then, it is a bit of a strange pattern to call one `run()` method from another.